# Google Flight RPC and building a JSON array

Tags: php, json, curl, http-post, rpc

I am trying to use the [Google Flight RPC](http://www.google.com/flights/rpc) but am having trouble building a json array to post to it. The only documentation I've found is [here](http://www.nohup.in/blog/using-json-google-flights). It describes what needs to be sent but doesn't explain how to construct the json array. Specifically, using PHP, I'm not sure how to build and post a json array using the following example from part 1 of the linked documentation.

```
[,[[,"fs","[,[,[\"SJC\"]\n,\"2012-04-05\",[\"EWR\",\"JFK\",\"LGA\"]\n,\"2012-04-12\"]\n]\n"]
]
,[,[[,"b_ca","54"]
,[,"f_ut","search;f=SJC;t=EWR,JFK,LGA;d=2012-04-05;r=2012-04-12"]
,[,"b_lr","11:36"]
,[,"b_lr","1:1528"]
,[,"b_lr","2:1827"]
,[,"b_qu","3"]
,[,"b_qc","1"]
]
]
]
```

The above does not appear to be properly formatted to be put into a json array. Additionally, HTTP request headers are needed. I assume these are set via cURL? I'm not clear on the documentation on how to do this.

I've tried several attempts and I don't get back any of the responses that are shown in the documentation.

Edit: Awesome, I got a [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) for this question! I would appreciate help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to find any documentation either.

However, if you go to https://www.google.com/flights/, open chrome console or firebug, click the network tab, then run a search, you will see that headers and body it makes for the RPC POST.

Sample Headers from the transfer:

`Request URL:(I BROKE THE LINK) GOOGLE(dot)com /flights/rpc
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
:host:(I BROKE THE LINK) GOOGLE (dot) com
:method:POST
:path:/flights/rpc
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:/
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length:169
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
cookie:PREF=ID=f472fc4bbb95bc2b:U=9da5b7e4c1d04bda:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1390684154:LM=1390749713:GM=1:S=orUAMb3qaxBh99PJ; HSID=AHlw351sj7B7Om0t_; SSID=AKycPxLzyXkc4_tZJ; APISID=xKH5zAdc9vfBtiDy/Ab5TlD_Z4w2nP64Wl; SAPISID=7awo9qDssc3wr-fN/AQYOdvCN-I-UwtXQ1; NID=67=XnUn_DGdQDaeczlvXe-qTy9vy8gnQwhFwfRi52TRFS-_Dg-J58CgTGUY6Tkn3cCJYCcVJhK8unOrdffpgzeKed2jPqSazVI4Xplo5fW8-6wXoNi97L2gdoaOms0dKj4iOODoZpzd4DG_8YdQQcH6fl5xY__N929CJr8pdcAUwgnKf8X_mI8sLSB7CKVyS4ZvbGMCAiMLwIs1gJJz-UbppSj; S=travel-flights=5OJmMrbJoqLfOFzkZy285A; SID=DQAAAM0AAAAIGD56aXyxAxrRCSROmPy8AEtV3DaEwKT48aaZ98S35Nss09ishDZ3RxNT6ksikfAOJo-MLYVodF3jr-6imwzC8tRd7cxe-OoyafCZiGaf0qhp-yza4VZlAMInxGPhVae7wSXCRXlqb-wbYHBCHUSz_K5kYpvKwqC8pWuQ_6AUZa3WWqB6OmYpxuihxn3UxSve95zpkziyaDX0JFzUjyWX-0O_iIWZiEztywwyKVWCVv27ByGjIYTYV1G2byExt5M9-kEFpE_v0x8KgU7vleT
dnt:1
origin:(I BROKE THE LINK) SSL GOOGLE(dot)com
referer:(I BROKE THE LINK) SSL GOOGLE(dot)com  flights
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
x-gwt-cctoken:ADS25WMm8S7W0MlpX1-Lf_yNzQCrke7t6OvH2kFLkBJIH_Q-YTuu8VSHmgIxzFtGaL87SsM5PcZECRBP7IqMCbM5QKFVdWrw9hRIkHoL5oiyCzEu2ZCnKuhqvv2sUKcg4Z_HnajCZmM7aQ9nYsVMQnFxqrkgB2Cz7rAIP47zPJ_rakoyxlGE4yJvcuUeiQ
x-gwt-module-base:https://www.google.com/flights/static/
x-gwt-permutation:C8210E5F468630F84E578D8EDE10A1A0
Request Payload
[,[[,"no","[]","1531191655318648",11]],[,[[,"b_al","no:74"],[,"b_ahr","no:s"],[,"b_ca","103:34541"],[,"b_pe","4F2F79B9E3FB0.A40E22A.71A7"],[,"b_qu","0"],[,"b_qc","1"]]]]
Response Headersview source
alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:75
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Sat, 22 Feb 2014 05:00:17 GMT
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:GSE
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block`

So, what you will likely have to do to get this to work correctly is to make a GET on the path /flights and read the headers, then put the headers in your POST request. (I have had to do similar things in the past). In order to figure out what fields are what I would play around with selecting different fields and seeing what changes in the JSON data that it posts.